# Folding cells in jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-lab

I'm working with JupyterLab 3.0.14 and I swear a few weeks ago I was able to collapse all cells between two markdown cells with H1 titles in it.

I don't mean clicking the blue rectangle at the left side of the cell. There was a white triangle that let me collapse all cells between that H1 and the next one like the red one drawn in the screenshot.

I'm working with a large notebook and that feature would be fantastic.
Is it possible that I override that feature?

No updates of JupyterLab (as far as I know). My notebook preferences are just:

{
"codeCellConfig": {
"lineNumbers": true,
}
}

Thx in advance! Rgds!

[View screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DW94.png)

Comment: This feature is available in JupyterLab 3.1, not 3.0. I refer to it as "collapsible headings". There is no need to change any configuration for it to work.

Comment: It would look like you got a downgrade, for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered by [@krassowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6646912/krassowski) via comments:

> This feature is available in JupyterLab 3.1, not 3.0. I refer to it as "collapsible headings". There is no need to change any configuration for it to work.

> It would look like you got a downgrade, for some reason.

Thank you!

```
$ conda update --all
```

solved it ;)